# General Strategy for Derivations in Propositional Logic

Tags: logic

In Propositional Logic, one is often tasked with showing that some particular formula is a theorem of a given deductive system, i.e. $\emptyset \vdash \psi$. These formulas can look very simple and intuitive, e.g. $(\alpha \rightarrow \alpha)$, but the derivation can be rather cumbersome. That examples takes around 6 steps for instance, and is one of the simpler cases.

My question is immediate then: **Is there any way of anticipating the correct strategy for making such derivations, and thus avoiding the lengthy 'trial and error' process of applying different axioms (and rules of inference) until something works?**

Essentially, are there any 'tricks' that are unlikely to appear in notes etc. but which you are aware of the help look ahead and spot the right path?

For completeness (no pun intended), I've included the particular deductive system I am working with below, and a few indicative theorems.

$((\neg \alpha \rightarrow \alpha)\rightarrow\alpha))$

$(\neg\neg\alpha\rightarrow\alpha)$

$(\neg\alpha\rightarrow(\alpha\rightarrow\beta))$

**EDIT**

The above cases can be dealt with a little more tidily by applying the Deduction Theorem. Do any other results like this exist? Also, supposing the Deduction Theorem cannot be used, do strategies still exist?

---

Let $\mathcal{L}_0=\mathcal{L}[\{\neg, \rightarrow\}]$. **Define the system $L_0$ as follows**:

An axiom of $L_0$ is any formula of $\mathcal{L}_0$ of the form

- (A1) $(\alpha \rightarrow ( \beta \rightarrow \alpha))$
- (A2) $((\alpha \rightarrow ( \beta \rightarrow \gamma) \rightarrow ((\alpha \rightarrow \beta) \rightarrow ( \alpha \rightarrow \gamma)))$
- (A3) $((\neg \beta \rightarrow \neg \alpha ) \rightarrow (\alpha \rightarrow \beta))$

The only rule of inference in $L_0$ is *modus ponens*, i.e. from $\alpha$ and $(\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$ infer $\beta$.

Comment: One possible strategy is to use the proof of the deduction theorem to find the formal proof.

Comment: Ah, the age-old question of how to do Hilbert-style proofs. We'd all benefit if someone dedicated a book on how to work with them. There are some relevant posts here with suggestions, search for Hilbert.

Comment: One might look into using a theorem prover.  There exist certain strategies one can use when using a theorem prover also, such as resonance and using hints.

Answer (score 2):

Some proofs of the completeness of a propositional proof system can actually be turned easily to an algorithm for proving any propositional statement $Q$ from a proposition statement $P$ if $Q$ is a consequence of $P$

This gives you a strategy for always finding proofs of propositional consequences.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood I understand what you mean and I will edit it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{sermon}

> In Propositional Logic, one is often tasked with showing that some particular formula is a theorem of a given deductive system [of a Hilbert style]

Often tasked by whom? Teachers with a very mean streak, perhaps. But surely very rarely in real logical life, so to speak. If you genuinely want to know whether a bunch of propositional assumptions do or don't entail a given conclusion (not just because some instructor asks you, and moreover asks you to do it with one hand tied behind your back), either you do a truth-table, or (usually faster) use a tableau, or (if you think the argument is valid and just want to confirm that) run up an informal natural deduction proof (the clue is in the name! -- such proofs do indeed  regiment natural ways of reasoning).

Over three-quarters of a century since Gentzen, it is pretty odd still to be making students tackle Hilbert systems. For there is very little serious *logical* interest in the combinatorial puzzle-solving task of finding Hilbert proofs (as opposed to proofs in more user-friendly systems of logic).

\end{sermon}

Comment: This isn't an answer.  One can also talk about how finding the shortest axiom for a given system under a given rule also necessitates a serious logical interest in finding such Hilbert proofs, and how theorem provers have gotten employed for finding such proofs.

Comment: It isn't an answer, it's a sermon. Or rant. But it is worth occasionally saying, as we don't want beginning students put off logic by having to tangle from the off with user-unfriendly Hilbert systems ...

Comment: Truth tables aren't possible for any infinite-valued logic, and natural deduction systems aren't feasible for say Lukasiewicz infinite-valued logic.  Natural deduction systems also can get characterized as misleading in that introduction and elimination rules sometimes do not enable the deduction of all tautologies for a given connective.  The introduction and elimination rules for "C" do not enable you to deduce CCCpqpp, nor doe the introduction and elimination rules for "E" (and those for "C") enable you to deduce EEEpqrEpEqr.

Comment: Using a truth table only tells you that a result holds for a particular model (or a certain class of models similar to a prototype).  A formal proof on the other hand tells you that *for any* model of the formulas of the system, a certain result holds under the conditions of the formal system (given soundness).  As too simple of any example, if you prove CCCpqrCqr from CCpqCCqrCpr and CpCqp under detachment, the formal proof tells that for any suitable model for "C", CCCpqrCqr follows.  This includes 2-valued logic, Lukasiewicz 3-valued logic, AND Lukasiewicz infinite-valued logic.

Comment: Natural deduction derivations of *theorems* also *only* end up proving one theorem at a time.  Truth-tables also only end up only establishing one tautology at a time.  Admittedly they can give you other tautologies when you interpret them, but even then they only give you tautologies according to a pattern of sorts.  On the other hand, Hilbert-*Frege* style proofs (usually) end up establishing *many* theorems when someone tries to prove just one theorem.  For instance, if you prove CCpqCCrpCrq in the Hilbert-Frege system {CpCqp, CCpCqrCCpqCpr} you'll prove two other theorems along the way...

Comment: At least probably prove them or substitution instances of them... CpCCqCrsCCqrCqs and CCpCqCrsCpCCqrCqs.

If you prove CCpqCCrpCrq using natural deduction, you'll just end up proving CCpqCCrpCrq.  Using truth tables, sure you can interpret it as establishing theorems like CpCqCrCCpqCCrpCrq, CpCNqCrCCpqCCrpCrq... but notice that those plenty of those theorems involve negations.  So, if truth tables get interpreted as implying more than one theorem, then truth tables can have irrelevant implciations in the sense that negation might not even come as part of the logical language.

Comment: In just the same sense that Hilbert-Frege style proofs establishing many theorems en route to the target conclusion, a natural deduction derivation establishes many sequents en route to the conclusion. There is no relevant difference.

Comment: "In just the same sense that Hilbert-Frege style proofs establishing many theorems en route to the target conclusion, a natural deduction derivation establishes many sequents en route to the conclusion."  Those "manys" are not equivalent in general, and in general you imply more sequents from the Hilber-Frege style proofs.  Yes, if you derive $\vdash$CCpqCCrpCrq in a natural deduction system, in one derivation you can get 1. {Cpq, Crp, r} $\vdash$ q, 2. {Cpq, Crp} $\vdash$ Crq, 3. Cpq $\vdash$ CCrpCrq also. But if you axiomatically prove it with condensed detachment from {CpCqp, CCpCqrCCpqCpr}

Comment: You have available 1. $\vdash$ CpCCqCrsCCqrCqs, 2. p $\vdash$ CCqCrsCCqrCqs, 3. {p, CqCrs} $\vdash$ CCqrCqs, 4. {p, CqCrs, Cqr} $\vdash$ Cqs, 5. {p, CqCrs, Cqr, q} $\vdash$ s, 6. $\vdash$ CCpCqCrsCpCCqrCqs, 7. CpCqCrs $\vdash$ CpCCqrCqs, 8. {CpCqCrs, p} $\vdash$ CCqrCqs, 9. {CpCqCrs, p, Cqr} $\vdash$ Cqs, 10. {CpCqCrs, p, Cqr, q} $\vdash$ s, 11.  ⊢CCpqCCrpCrq, 12.  Cpq ⊢ CCrpCrq , 13. {Cpq, Crp} ⊢ Crq, 14. {Cpq, Crp, r} ⊢ q.  So all of the sequents which the natural deudction derivation gives you come out of the axiomatic proof.  The converse does not come out of the natural deduction proof.

Comment: Oops... for the natural deduction system, you can also get 4. {Cpq, Crp, r} $\vdash$ p.  It still holds that you get more from the axiomatic proof though.

Comment: So a user directed me to one of your writings about axiomatic proofs http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/ProofSystems.pdf.  You selected the example of proving (P$\land$Q)$\vdash$P in Mendelsohn's system with definitions.  I find the example a bit strange, since a more general result is $\lnot$(P$\rightarrow$Q)$\vdash$P.

Comment: Also, natural deduction derivations *only* end up proving the formula in the a priori form specified.  Sometimes, there exists a more general formula.  For example, if you try to prove the converse of self-distribution: CCCpqCprCpCqr via natural deduction you'll *only* get that formula.  But if you try to prove it axiomatically using condensed detachment you will, or at least *can*, get the more general CCCpqCrsCrCqs.  As another example, see the comments here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/947270/can-hilbert-style-prove-my-tautology/988365#988365

Answer (score 0):

There exists a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/756064/general-strategy-for-derivations-in-propositional-logic/760368#760368)... my best response to that question may be the September 30th response (I employ the same conventions in this answer as I did in that answer).  Condensed detachment may help, as well as using a theorem-prover.

For this system you can prove everything by the deduction (meta) theorem, a theorem which allows to get NCpNq (this is Polish notation) from "p" and "q", and a form of proof-by-contradiction.  The proof-by-contradiction roughly goes "if we assume the negation of a well-formed formula "Nw" and it leads to a contradiction, then the formula "w" is either a theorem or true under the scope of the other hypotheses."  The relevant theorems you need for this are (in Polish notation):

Recursive Letter Prefixing [RLP]: CpCqp

Self-Distribution [SD]: CCpCqrCCpqCpr  [these two give you The Deduction Theorem, and if you have The Deduction Theorem, then these two are theorems].

Conjunction-introduction [Ki]: CpCqNCpNq.

and

Negation elimination [No]: CCNpNCqNNqp.

I used [Prover9](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~mccune/mace4/) to find proofs of the last two theorems in this system.

Proofs of CNNpp and CNpCpq emerged when I ran Prover9 for the proofs of negation elimination and conjunction introduction.  Now say you want to prove Clavius: CCNppp, which you mentioned before.  We can assume CNpp as a hypothesis and proceed as follows.

```
 hypothesis 1 |  CNpp  
 hypothesis 2 || Np   
 D1.2       3 || p    
 D[Ki.3]*4  4 || CNaNCpNa
 D4.2*5     5 || NCpNNp
 Ci 2-5 *6  6 |  CNpNCpNNp
 D[No.6]*7  7 |  p
 Ci 1-7*8   8    CCNppp
```

C2-2 is the law of identity.  C2-3 is the hypothesis.

```
 hypothesis   1 | CNpp
 D[RLP.Ki]*2  2 | CaCbCcNCbNc  (this enables C2-Ki)
 D[SD.2]*3    3 | CCabCaCcNCbNc  
 D3.1*4       4 | CNpCcNCpNc  (this enables C2-4)
 D[SD.4]*5    5 | CCNpcCNpNCpNc
 D5.[Cpp]*6   6 | CNpNCpNNp
 D[No.6]*7    7 | p
 Ci 1-7*8     8   CCNppp

 axiom        0 CCNpNqCqp (not used here)
 axiom        1 CpCqp
 axiom        2 CCpCqrCCpqCpr
 theorem      3 CpCqNCpNq
 theorem      4 CCNpNCqNNqp
 D2.1*5       5 CCpqCpp
 D5.1*6       6 Cpp  (this enables C1-1)
 D1.3*7       7 CpCqCrNCqNr (this enables C1-Ki)
 D1.4*8       8 CpCqCrCsNCrNs (this enables C1-2)
 D1.1*9       9 CpCqCrq (this enables C1-RLP)
 D1.2*10     10 CpCCqCrsCCqrCqs
 D2.10*11    11 CCpCqCrsCpCCqrCqs
 D11.8*12    12 CpCCqrCqCsNCrNs (this enables C1-3) 
 D12.6*13    13 CCpqCpCrNCqNr (this enables C1-4)
 D11.3*14    14 CCpqCCprCpNCqNr (this enables C1-5)  
 D1.6*15     15 CpCqq (this enables C1-Cpp)
 C2.14*16    16 CCCpqCprCCpqCpNCqNr
 D16.15*17   17 CCpqCpNCqNp  (this enables C1-6)
 D1.4*18     18 CpCCNqNCrNNrq
 D2.18*19    19 CCpCNqNCrNNrCpq
 D19.17*20   20 CCNppp
```

A useful pattern here is to take any axiom or theorem "x", then go D[RLP.x], and then distribute that result.  D[SD].[D[RLP.x]].  Interestingly enough, you can prove CNpCpq by starting this way... D D[SD].[D[RLP.0]].[RLP] is a proof of CNpCpq.